# How to remember NFA's choice on a certain computation?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

I'm working on solving the question answered at this page but with different values at the table, my alphabet is {a,b,c}
[Words that have the same right- and left-associative product](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/words-that-have-the-same-right-and-left-associative-product)

Currently I'm in the stage where I have drawn the DFA of the multiplication table, found its reverse which was an NFA.

Here is the NFA I got by reversing the multiplication table's DFA
[image]

I apology for the miss draw, but I hope its readable.

Now I have taken the input "abcb" and applied it on the above NFA, and I have gone through this tree [image]

As you can see here that the input is all consumed at the branch "C" and I could reach the Final State. Would someone elaborate to me how can I backtrack from that branch which is "C" in this case and indicate that the "C" is the state which shall be marked as the Final State my NFA?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "backtrack" here. How does any of this relate to the titular question? *Who* wants to remember something -- you, some algorithm, or the automaton?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let the input be $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. As you mention, it is easy to compute the left-associative product $L_n$ "as you go": $L_{m+1} = L_m x_{m+1}$. The right-associative product recurrence has the wrong direction: $R_m = x_{m+1} R_{m+1}$. To cope with that, at each step you have to *guess* the value of $R_{m+1}$; it needs to be a value which conforms to your earlier guess of $R_m$ and to the value of $x_{m+1}$. At the end, compare your initial guess of $R_1$ to the value of $L_n$. Arrange things so that you only need to keep track of finitely many values of products.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm a real beginner at this kind of science, I couldn't understand your answer. Can you try to put it in a simpler form for me to understand? - Also how do I can keep track of anything without having memory?

Comment: @CSGuy Unfortunately, I am not willing to provide further hints.

Comment: That's fine, thank you I will study a bit more and try to decrypt the answer.